# change color of default option in select

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying customize `select`, but I cannot to change color of `default` option using css.

I tried to use `.choose-flat__select option[default]` and `.choose-flat__select option:first-child`, but it did not help.

Please see the example: https://jsfiddle.net/1v76mvo7/

Also, I tried to change it using jQuery:

```
$("#year-ready").find("option:first").attr("default", true).css('color', 'gray');
```

but unsuccessfully.

Is it possible to change color using `CSS`?

**UPDATE:**

I think that described a bit incorrect. I want that `default` option (in my case 'Year...') has `gray` color when it is selected: [image], but if I select other options they should have `black` color: [image]

Comment: As far as I know `default` is not an HTML property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand, you want to change the color of the selected option. If it is then try the following css.

```
.choose-flat__select
{
  color: yourColorCode;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkodtrcr/)

**UPDATE**

As per your updated question, you can do this by using Javascript.

```
$("#year-ready").change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val == yourDefaultValue)
   {
       $(this).addClass("default");
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).removeClass("default");
   }
});
```

And add the style in your css

```
.default
{
    color: gray;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ofr0719/)

Comment: Thanks! It suits me, but as I understand it is not possible to do with css only?

Comment: You can by adding `required` at the `select`. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/t3nv0nzz/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
<select id="year-ready" name="" class="choose-flat__select">
  <option selected disabled>Year...</option>
  <option>2017</option>
  <option>2018</option>
  <option>2019</option>
  <option>2020</option>
  <option>2021</option>
</select>
```

if you don't wanna show your default, set it to hidden like this:

```
<option hidden selected disabled>Year...</option>
```

if you want to give many different colors, your can give your options some classes.

```
<option class="green" disabled selected>Year...</option>
<option class="red">2017</option>
```

[Fiddle Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/1v76mvo7/7/)